# push to viewController while keeping access to information on previous viewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, pushviewcontroller

I was wondering if it is possible to push to a new viewController while keeping access to data on the VC that did the pushing. I am wondering if there is a way to complete this, or if I could somehow make that specific information globally available to another view?

for example, I have users name and image being retrieved from firebase on profileVC, and I want to press a button that will send it to another ViewController that will display that name and image as well.

I will show below, how I call this information.

```
 class userProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell {

var user: User? {

didSet {

    configureMessageAcceptButton()
    let name = user?.name
    nameLabel.text = name

    guard let profileImageUrl = user?.profileImageUrl else { return }
    profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)
}
}



lazy var acceptButton: UIButton = {
     let button = UIButton(type: .system)
     button.setTitle("Loading", for: .normal)
     button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
     button.layer.borderColor = GREEN_Theme.cgColor
     button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
     button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
     button.setTitleColor(GREEN_Theme, for: .normal)
     button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAcceptRequest), for: .touchUpInside)
     return button
 }()

let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "users")
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return image
}()

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Jane John Doe"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    return label
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

  addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.anchors(top: topAnchor, topPad: 0, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left:      leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: 100, width: 200)
    setupProfileImageView()
    setupNameView()
}

func setupProfileImageView() {
    imageView.addSubview(self.profileImageView)
    self.profileImageView.anchors(top: nil, topPad: 0, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0, left: imageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 16, right: nil, rightPad: 0, height: 100, width: 100)
    self.profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.imageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.profileImageView.layer.zPosition = 10
    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    self.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.profileImageView.image=#imageLiteral(resourceName: "user")
}

 func setupNameView() {

imageView.addSubview(self.nameLabel)
self.nameLabel.anchors(top: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, topPad: 10, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0, left: profileImageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: nil, rightPad: 0, height: 30, width: 100)
self.nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.nameLabel.layer.zPosition = 10
self.nameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true


 }


@objc func handleAcceptRequest() {
    let user = self.user
    let username = user?.name

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you Sure? ",message:" Would you like to accept \(username!) to complete your job?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
           print("you pressed Yes, please button")
       })

    let continueButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.saveUserData(didAccept: "yes")
        let acceptWorker = acceptWorkerViewController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: acceptWorker)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
           print("you pressed Continue")

       })




    continueButton.setValue(GREEN_Theme, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    cancelButton.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    alert.addAction(cancelButton)
    alert.addAction(continueButton)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }



fileprivate func configureMessageAcceptButton() {

    guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let user = self.user else { return }

    if currentUID != user.uid {

        imageView.addSubview(self.acceptButton)
        imageView.addSubview(self.sendMessageButton)
              self.acceptButton.anchors(top: profileImageView.topAnchor, topPad: 0, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0, left: nil, leftPad: 0, right: imageView.rightAnchor, rightPad: 16, height: 40, width: 120)
              self.sendMessageButton.anchors(top: acceptButton.bottomAnchor, topPad: 16, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0, left: acceptButton.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: nil, rightPad: 0, height: 40, width: 120)
        acceptButton.setTitle("Accept Request", for: .normal)
        sendMessageButton.setTitle("Send Message", for: .normal)

    } else {
            print("this is the currentUser profile")
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



 }
```

sorry for the intense amount of code, I just wanted to show all of the code that represents what I am saying. in func handleAcceptRequest(), that's how I am pushing to a new ViewController. Is it possible to keep the data that's inside this viewController when pushing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo code of a Master->Details scenario where the detail viewController needs to access data in the Master viewController. I think this may answer your question

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var some_string = "Hello, World"

    func showDetailController() {
      //code to instantiate the detailViewController
      detailViewController.myParentViewContoller = self
    }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

and then the detail

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
   var myParentViewController: : MasterViewController? = nil
   .
   .
   .

   func printMessage() {
      let message = self.myParentViewController.some_string
      print(message)
   }
}
```

Note there are probably 34 more ways to do the same thing; you could pass the data via a segue or populate the detail vars from the master etc.